# QGIS - How to randomly generate 1 point per 2 hectares inside multiple polygons based upon their individual total areas?

Tags: qgis, point, random, research

For the purposes of creating random survey plot locations in a forest.

I want to randomly generate 1 point(plot) per 2 hectares with a minimum of 100m between each point (plot) inside multiple polygons of the same layer.

There are several hundred polygons each with different total areas (hectares).

[image: Image shows polygons representing different forest types labeled by area (hectares)]

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a polygon grid (Menu Vector > Research Tools > Create Grid) with spacing so that every grid cell has an area of 1 hectare - e.g. rectangle 100 m * 200 m
2. Create the intersection of the grid with your initial polygons.
3. Run Menu Vector > Research Tools > Random points in polygons. Use the layer created in step 2 as input layer and set minimum distance between points to 100 and number of points for each feature to 1.

[See also here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/380388/re-locating-points-randomly-at-certain-distance-in-qgis/380390#380390) for more options.