# Automatically generate random points and add to attribute table

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, geometry-generator

I would like if it is possible to modify an attribute table from a Geometry Generator expression.

My goal is, while digitizing points (with *Add point feature* tool), use a Geometry Generator expression, to automatically add 10 points randomly distributed in space with a maximum distance and at the same time add to the attribute table 10 new records.

**Example Add point feature**
[image]

**Example Random points added at 10 meter max. distance**
[image]

Comment: Geometry Generator is for visualization only, you can't create new features with it. For this, you have to use Geometry by expression, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392619/88814 For creating random points, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380390/88814

Comment: After you've digitized your points you can use geometry by expression to create a new layer, then merge this with your original layer

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. The expression `project($geometry,100000,radians(rand(0,360)))` is, in part, a solution.
I think I could have a complete solution, by developing a button toolbar that does something like _Add random point feature_. Could recommend me any website or tutorial that explains how to start create QGIS buttons?

Comment: Take a look at "QGIS Actions" for this purpose.